# Formation of groups in a webpage

Tags: website-design, design-patterns

I have to make a webpage to associate users (around 30) together into groups. I have thought about a vertical list of users with radio-buttons (number of users) in the line. Example:

```
  groups     1 2 3 4 5
John doe 1   O O O O O
John doe 2   O O O O O
John doe 3   O O O O O
John doe 4   O O O O O
John doe 5   O O O O O
```

And a column would be a group (O are radio-buttons). But it seems ugly for 30 persons and it must be confuse to see groups... Is there another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

What about autocompleting the names of the members. Something like this:

1. Each group has a box with a list of its members.
2. Each box has a search form that can be used to look for the users (ideally with autocomplete).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4uLM.png]

If the users doesn't know the other users and they know better which groups are there it could be done the other way around: boxes for each user and search for the groups.

Comment: It's would be very cool too, I wonder just if 30 initial box would have good size..

Comment: You can sort them as a grid. How is the groups/users proportion going to be? How many users and groups are there?

Comment: I want to group users together. I think it will have around 30 users, so I will have 30 groups maximum (each user alone). It will be a grid of 3x10.

After, I can make a dynamic system and useless boxes can disappear (if an user join a group, I will need 29 boxes, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

- Create a five (5) column layout (whereas each column = a group) and produce a drag-and-drop interface from it
- Drag 'names' from one column (group) to another, respectively

Comment: Ah yes, I like this idea ! Is it difficult to do with jquery?

Comment: In my opinion? No, it's not difficult, but that depends on where you are with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and proven way, as far as I know, is by enabling multi-selection.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0oXMM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The mockup above follows a similar design pattern for this as Google use in their Gmail for administrating what label/folder an email or group of emails should be associated with. This is a very efficient and streamlined way of handling this task. The administrating of user association that this regards would be totally transferable to a similar solution.

Comment: The problem is that we haven't got any global view :/ I need all on the same page..

Comment: ok, I'm not sure what that entails.. =)